# Infer typescript nested generic type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
function test<
  Feature extends { shape: Geometry; properties: Properties },
  Geometry extends geojson.Geometry,
  Properties extends {}
>() {
  const addFeature = (feature: Feature) => {
    switch (feature.shape.type) {
      case "Point":
        break;
    }
  };

  return {
    addFeature,
  };
}

test<{ shape: GeoJSON.Polygon; properties: {} }, GeoJSON.Polygon, {}>();
```

Is there any way to not be required to pass in second generic and third generics? I want to be able to do this:

```
test<{ shape: GeoJSON.Polygon; properties: {} }>();
```

and have typescript infer the other two generics

Answer (score 0):

You can omit Feature defenition completely, because it depends on `Geometry` and `Properties`

```
function test<
  Geometry extends GeoJSON.Geometry,
  Properties extends {},
>() {
  const addFeature = (feature: { shape: Geometry; properties: Properties }) => {
    switch (feature.shape.type) {
      case "Point":
        break;
    }
  };

  return {
    addFeature,
  };
}

test<GeoJSON.Polygon, {}>();
```

or define it elsewhere

```
type Feature<G extends GeoJSON.Geometry, P extends {}> = {
  shape: G;
  properties: P;
}

function test<
  Geometry extends GeoJSON.Geometry,
  Properties extends {},
>() {
  const addFeature = (feature: Feature<Geometry, Properties>) => {
    switch (feature.shape.type) {
      case "Point":
        break;
    }
  };

  return {
    addFeature,
  };
}

test<GeoJSON.Polygon, {}>();
```

but it will still have some issues, if you got a lot of Feature props